# Create a grid view for a PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, view, grid

So I tried to figure out how to take my PHP query and display them in a grid view.
I want to make it a grid of 3 columns so it looks like this: First column: 1, 2, 3 Second column: 4, 5, 6 and so on...

Here is my code to view MySQL query via PHP:

```
<div class='main_col'> <!--Start of the Main-->
<div class='main_content'>
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

$select_games = "SELECT * FROM games";

$run_games = mysql_query($select_games);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){

$game_id = $row['game_id'];
$game_name = $row['game_name'];
$game_category = $row['game_name'];
$game_keywords = $row['game_name'];
$game_image = $row['game_image'];

?>

<p><a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><?php echo $game_name; ?></a></p>

<a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><img src="images/games_images/<?php echo $game_image; ?>" width="120" /></a>

<?php } ?>
</div>
</div> <!--End of the Main-->
```

I tried this:

```
<div class='main_col'> <!--Start of the Main-->
<div class='main_content'>
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

$select_games = "SELECT * FROM games";

$run_games = mysql_query($select_games);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){

$game_id = $row['game_id'];
$game_name = $row['game_name'];
$game_category = $row['game_name'];
$game_keywords = $row['game_name'];
$game_image = $row['game_image'];

?>

<table>

<tr>
<td><p><a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><?php echo $game_name; ?></a></p>

<a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><img src="images/games_images/<?php      echo $game_image; ?>" width="120" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div> <!--End of the Main-->
```

Suggestions anybody? :(

Comment: How exactly is this attempting to form a grid? I'm not seeing a single <table> tag or even any type of block element

Comment: Well, this is the basic code that shows the items in a list...

Comment: What have you tried to "make it a grid view" so far by yourself? We try to help you with what you're doing, not do all the work for you.

Comment: I tried to put the: echo lines under the PHP code in a <table> via HTML

Comment: Did they contain the correct <tr> and <td> tags? Probably not. I've posted a solution below.

Comment: Thanks again Tularis :), I'm a little new to PHP so I don't basically know how to claim my thoughts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should really switch away from using the *deprecated* mysql extension. Instead you should either use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO).

Next, what you want it a table which contains 3 columns. Each data field should contain 3 games. So that means that after every 3 games, you want to make a  and after every 9 games, start a new row. You can use the modulo-operator (%) to see when you have had 3 (or 6 or 9, etc.) games, and when you have had 9/18/27/etc. games, like so:

```
<div class='main_col'> <!--Start of the Main-->
<div class='main_content'>
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

$run_games = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games");

echo '<table>';
$games = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){
   // make a new row after 9 games
   if($games%9 == 0) {
      if($games > 0) {
         // and close the previous row only if it's not the first
         echo '</tr>';
      }
      echo '<tr>';
   }
   // make a new column after 3 games
   if($games%3 == 0) {
      if($games > 0) {
         // and only close it if it's not the first game
         echo '</td>';
      }
      echo '<td>';
   }

   $game_id = $row['game_id'];
   $game_name = $row['game_name'];
   $game_category = $row['game_name'];
   $game_keywords = $row['game_name'];
   $game_image = $row['game_image'];
   ?>

   <a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><?php echo $game_name; ?></a><br />
   <a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><img src="images/games_images/<?php echo $game_image; ?>" width="120" /></a>
   <?php 
   $games++; // increment the $games element so we know how many games we've already processed
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</div> <!--End of the Main-->
```

Alternatively, if you simply want 1 game per field, you can use something like this:

```
<div class='main_col'> <!--Start of the Main-->
<div class='main_content'>
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

$run_games = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games");

echo '<table>';
$games = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){
   // make a new row after 3 games
   if($games%3 == 0) {
      if($games > 0) {
         // and only close it if it's not the first game
         echo '</tr>';
      }
      echo '<tr>';
   }

   $game_id = $row['game_id'];
   $game_name = $row['game_name'];
   $game_category = $row['game_name'];
   $game_keywords = $row['game_name'];
   $game_image = $row['game_image'];
   ?>
   <td>
   <a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><?php echo $game_name; ?></a><br />
   <a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><img src="images/games_images/<?php echo $game_image; ?>" width="120" /></a>
   </td>
   <?php 
   $games++; // increment the $games element so we know how many games we've already processed
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</div> <!--End of the Main-->
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that now, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: added a tiny fix, noticed it was missing a $games++; element at the end of the loop

Comment: Wow its working! but there is a tiny problem, the first 3 games looks good, there is a name above the image, but the rest rows shows the name at the right side of the game image... :o

Comment: Could you post your HTML somewhere so I can have a look at what you mean? Perhaps including a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, basically I'm designing an online games website (legal), so maybe some tips to it will also help :D I built it to test my learning on it ;) http://www.movga.com -- This is the homepage, so look how they appear :/

Comment: Well, In this case I'm wondering why: 1. you want to display the name at all, and 2. why you want to have 3 games per field instead of 1 game per field (easier). I've added a 2nd answer which explains how to make it 1 game per field

Comment: I don't know, first of all I should use the game name there so the user know what game it is. Second of all Grid view looks much better I think, its more "space friendly" :)

Comment: I think I fixed it using divs and some css :)

Comment: Try my 2nd answer. It simply makes a table with 1 game per field. Still containing 3 columns (and an infinite number of rows)

Comment: I will try that later on :), you my friend deserve a medal ;) Look now at my website, it looks better now :D